# PowerBI - Show the sum of the value group by subscription ID but in graph show only by subscription name

Tags: azure, powerbi, dax, powerquery

I've this Power BI graph with Subscription Name and Subscription Id by Cost:

[image]

and I would like to see the subscription name but group by id, so I want to display only the Subscrption Name by Cost but with Subscription Id granularity.

If I remove the subscription ID, it always groups by Subscription Name, where there is only one single bar for Microsoft Azure.

I tried to use this DAX measure:

```
Field Color = 
IF (FIRSTNONBLANKVALUE('Dim Azure Resource'[Subscription Id], 1), "#FFFFFF", "#000000")
```

and use it in conditional formatting to change the colour, but without success:

[image]

The graph output desire will be:

[image]

Sample data:

```
Subscription Name Subscrption Id     Cost
Microsoft Azure   Subscription Id 1  1412
Microsoft Azure   Subscription Id 2  34
Microsoft Azure   Subscription Id 3  214
Microsoft Azure   Subscription Id 4  231
Microsoft Azure   Subscription Id 5  645
```

Can anyone please help me in achieving this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this alternative solution it was possible to solve the problem:
https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Show-the-sum-of-the-value-group-by-subscription-ID-but-in-graph/td-p/3209368#M1082317

Comment: “While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.”

Answer (score 0):

Logically it is not feasible till April-2023 update in Power BI.If you used "FirstNonBlankValue" or Left Function it evaluate the expression on all Y Axis and change the color of whole lineitem.You can post this suggest to https://ideas.powerbi.com/

for futur availibility.

Thanks